# React error handling in mimified file

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I need to log an error occured on my website. The best way will be to log a place where it occure in code. The problem is when i use

> componentDidCatch()

then i have an error stack wchich show me excatly where the problem occur.

But the probleme begins when i mimified my code and push it to the production serwer. Error stack on production is unreadable. So is there any way to get correct error stack from production ? Or i have to write error handling in every component  instead of using componentDIdCatch inside top tree component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, componentDidCatch is not useful for troubleshooting in production. It looks like the intention was just to prevent the blank screen of death from happening and allow to gracefully fallback to some user-friendly error page.
As you said, you'll have to write error handling in every component.