# React ErrorBoundary shows wrong line and column numbers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've designed my application with `Webpack v5.x` and `Typescript` with `React v17.x`.

I've created an `ErrorBoundary` component for my application, but the problem is I cannot get the original sourceMapped error line number from the `.tsx` files.

```js
// webpack.config.js
{
...,
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Inside the `ErrorBoundary` component I've `componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo)` lifecycle function. If I console the `error` object inside the `componentDidCatch` function I found the error message with the original `.tsx` file with the exact line number.

But If I console the `error.stack` it shows the compiled file name and line number.

So, how could I get the original sourceMapped file and line number from the `error.stack`?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386890/react-error-handling-in-mimified-file)'s a similar question that's been answered:

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably TypeScript error.
Old issue but seems to come back - i've got similar problem
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8783*

**EDIT:**
Try with *React Developer Tools* turned off if You use chrom based browser - it helped in my case.